# Passing data from GRUB2 module to kernel during boot-up

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, grub2

Is there any way to pass data from a custom GRUB2 module to kernel, so that a kernel driver module can use it?

I am writing a GRUB2 module that process some data and need to get this data output passed to kernel. The data consists of some integers and long integers.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shared data between GRUB2 and Linux Kernel driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590189/shared-data-between-grub2-and-linux-kernel-driver)